# FCM notifications with image on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Prephase:**

My app is build to serve a particular hardware that connects to device via bluetooth and as such does not require internet to function. We do not have server that app connects to.

I have a requirement that monthly promotional notification needs to be triggered with a title and image.

**Problem:**

FCM provides [Cloud Messaging](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/dabblepushtest01/notification/compose) right from FCM console for promotional notifications that can be sent to entire user base.

However, "Notification messages" does not have provision for "image" by default and I can trigger them with data payload but "onMessageReceived" is not triggered when app is in background(in which case notification will only show title and no image).

FCM guarantees "onMessageReceived" for every "Data Messages" sent but there is no provision to trigger that from console.

I have seen some answers with "click_action" tag workaround in notification payload but that also I cannot add from console.

It seems that the only option is to send a POST request with data payload to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. while this works the Promotional Notifications will be triggered by marketing team situated offshore who have no idea how a HTTP client works and there's also an issue with scheduling notifications.

Is there a way to do this without setting up a server and a notification panel?

P.S. As much as FCM is useful I do not understand the design philosophy behind such limitations on message types.

Comment: Who is hosting the images? Why can't the Android app download them as part of the message (i.e. a url in the message)?

Comment: @MorrisonChang there's a limitation. Let's say the app is closed, then it's not possible to display a notification with an image (read : `but "onMessageReceived" is not triggered when app is in background(in which case notification will only show title and no image).`). I personally have the same problem and I'm looking for an answer as well.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Images are hosted on google drive. Your second question is answered by ZUNJAE.